# Как исправить регулярное выражение?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Для строки мне нужно,составить регулярное выражение, которое смотрит, есть ли в первых тегах слово World и asdf . 
Я составил такую:

> <.*(World)[\s\S]+?(/asdf/")[\S]+?>"

Для такой строки мне должно возвращаться false

```
<ru(тут может быть все что угодно):World xmlns="asd" t="http://dddd.com"></ss><cast xmlns="asdf"></World>
```

тк поиск должен быть только в подстроке 
`<ru(тут может быть все что угодно):World xmlns="asd" t="http://dddd.com">`
Но возвращает true тк слово asdf содержится в `<cast xmlns="asdf">`
Как сделать правильно?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/nw49xz/1

Answer (score 0):

> поиск должен быть только в подстроке  `<World xmlns="asd">`

Попробуйте такую регулярку.

```
<.*World[^>]*asdf[^>]
```

Также не будет лишним почитать (хотя бы в [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.96.D0.B0.D0.B4.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.B8_.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B2.D0.B0.D1.8F_.D0.BA.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.84.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F)) про квантификаторы, диапазоны и пр.

Comment: не работает(я немного подправил пример, но и до правки не работало)

Comment: У меня работает: https://regex101.com/r/3CIDik/1

Comment: у меня ничего не подсвечивается и наверху no match

Comment: Не знаю, что у Вас там подсвечивается или нет, но на regex101 видно, что что регулярка для Вашего примера делает именно то, что нужно. Совпадений (match) у Вас и не должно быть, т.к. регулярка смотрит, как Вы и говорите, 1й тег.

Comment: ознакомился с регулярками поглубже, спасибо. ответ понял.